# scp user1@host1:somefile user2@host2:somefile

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

When I attempt to perform a

`scp user1@host1:somfile user2@host2:somfile`

I get

`Host key verification failed.`

`lost connection`

The authentication to both hosts is ssh-key based, however for security reasons the private key is only stored on the host that issues the above command.

Another complication in this setup is, that host2 is SFTP-only, so no shell access there.

I tested with an older openssl/openssh (Debian lenny openssh-client 5.1) combination and a with latest openssl/openssh releases built from source (openssl 1.0.0c, openssh 5.8) as well. Same behavior.

It's also woth to mention that executing

`scp user1@host1:somfile somfile`

`scp somfile user2@host2:somfile`

sequentially through a temp file works.

What am I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The ssh-agent is running btw. As this is also indicated through the fact that the sequential commands are working fine

Comment: Re "host2 is SFTP-only" - the OpenSSH `scp` command does not use SFTP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until OpenSSH 5.7, copying between two hosts is done directly. In other words, the connection to `host2` is made *from `host1`*, using `host1`'s list of known hostkeys.

- You can add `host2` to the `known_hosts` file at `host1`, by simply connecting to it. Then use *agent forwarding* to let `host1` authenticate using your locally running agent:

  ```
  ssh -oForwardAgent=yes host1 ssh host2 true

  scp -oForwardAgent=yes user1@host1:somfile user2@host2:
  ```

  (`ssh` has a shortcut `-A` for this option. It can also be added to `~/.ssh/config`.)
- In 5.7 and later, you can use `scp -3` to force the copy to be made through your computer:

  ```
  scp -3 user1@host1:somfile user2@host2:
  ```

  This will probably be much slower because of *`host1` → you → `host2`*.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you have ssh-agent running, do you?